# Lazy Initialization of retrofit API response in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines, lazy-initialization

Hi friends here is my code it is part of my `ProfileViewModel` it is used by two fragments,
I want to get the value when it is useful because I am using this ViewModel for two fragment. so I
don't want initialize when don't using it, how can I archive it through lazy initialization , here
the response is the response returned by the retrofit, here the coroutine launched in
Dispatchers.IO and the response is parsed by my function `makeApiCall` it can handle the
success and error with a sealed class `Result` so it will return the response if it is success
else null, response can be also observed in the respective fragment with the respective function,
below is my code

```
val profile: ProfileModel  by lazy {  getProfile() }

init {
    getProfile()
}

fun getProfile() {
    Coroutines.io {
        makeApiCall(
            ProfileFragment.REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE
        ){
            repository.getProfile()
        }?.let { response ->
            form.name.postValue(
                response.profile.name
            )
            profile = response.profile
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want this why not just call `getProfile()` when you need it . Do not call it in `init` block. Also do not not delegate the property . Just initialize it or keep it null . You should require a `LiveData` to get the loading state callback.

Comment: i got it from lot of sarch on interner finally found that fun <T>lazyDeferred(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T) : Lazy<Deferred<T>>{
        return lazy {
            GlobalScope.async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY){
                block.invoke(this)
            }
        }
    }
and now in my code 
val profile by lazyDeferred {
        makeApiCall(
            ProfileFragment.REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE
        ){ repository.getProfile() }?.profile
    }
and in my fragment 
Coroutines.main {
            binding.profile = viewModel.profile.await()
        }
thanks you @ADM